# Firebase: Doubts about delete rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to test my delete rule with Firebase Simulator, and I want to be sure that I'm doing it ok.

Rule:

```
match /categories/{document=**} {
  allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/categories/$(document)).data.isActive == false;
}
```

When I test it using: /categories/xrzoUrdHZ0w9TJO38PiK, it seems working, because this category has the field 'isActive' == false.

But I'm not sure about this - $(document). It shouldn't be $(request.resource.data.id) or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the above rule that you have declared, you are checking the flag from the data that is present in the cloud firestore, not from the user request data.

Also, you are trying to read the same document again from firestore, since it'll cost you 1 read operation during the deletion of document. Above method should be used only when you want to validate data from different document

Security rules have access to new data(user request) and data present in cloud

```
//checking flag from user requested data
request.resource.data.isActive
//checking flag from data present in document in cloud firestore
resource.data.isActive
```

Use following rule to allow deletion if user requested data **isActive** is false

```
match /categories/{document=**} {
  allow delete: if request.resource.data.isActive == false;
}
```

and followin rule to allow deletion if **isActive** flag from data present in document is false

```
match /categories/{document=**} {
  allow delete: if resource.data.isActive == false;
}
```